# How quickly do events fire?

Tags: c#

I am developing an application to work alongside a hardware configuration.

The hardware connects to the application through a serial port in the application, and will be sending data from the hardware to the application at a fast rate (~2-4 μs).

My plan is to receive the data via serial port in the parent form, and then send this data to a User Control that is dedicated to displaying it, via an event.

While I've had no problem with directly transmitting it to a single form, I'm unfamiliar with events, and am not sure if the event will fire fast enough to smoothly handle the data.

My questions are:

- How fast can an event fire? Is it based off hardware, or are there software limitations?
- What are some drawbacks to handling data with this method?
- Are there better alternatives to passing data via an event?
- Is it at all feasible to process data at this rate?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. Events are plenty fast (a delegate call is almost as cheap as a direct call)
2. For smoothness, you only need as many batches per second as your frame rate (about 60 Hz)
3. Depending on your serial port vendor and settings, you might get considerable delay caused by buffering.
4. Processing data at "this" rate (500,000 samples per second) could very well be feasible, depending on how much processing you have to do.  Given the four orders of magnitude difference between your sample rate and the display update rate, it's worth batching them when doing screen updates, not trying to redraw 500,000 times per second.
5. No traditional "serial port", even the fancy USB-based ones, can transfer 500,000 samples per second.  (Best UART I've ever seen is 3 Mbps = 300,000 bytes per second, and each of your packets is probably more than one byte)
6. If 2-4 microseconds is the bit time, then you have nothing to worry about.  The serial port will buffer hundreds of bits before generating an event to your program.